# Find text in column one and copy value from next column to column 3 in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column 1 in my spread sheet contains text (just 1 word), 2nd column numbers and column 3 will have those numbers in specific order.
Example:

```
cell   values
A3     aaaa  
A4     bbbb  
A5     cccc  
A6     dddd  
A7     eeee  
A8     ffff  

B3     11  
B4     22  
B5     33  
B6     44  
B7     55  
B8     66
```

I want cell C3 to search the whole column A for a word `ffff` and once it found it, it would copy a value of the cell next to it in column B. So if the word `ffff` was in cell A8 the cell C3 would be `66` as B8=66. If `ffff` was in A5 than C3 would be `33` etc. After that I want C4 to find a word `cccc` in column A and copy value from next cell in column B and so on. Does anyone know how can I do it? Can this be done without using macros?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `VLOOKUP` function, e.g. in C3

`=VLOOKUP("ffff",A:B,2,FALSE)`

the 2 tells Excel to return the value from column 2 of the specified range (A:B) and FALSE means that only exact matches are considered - see Excel help for more on VLOOKUP

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I think I'm doing something wrong as I'm getting #REF! error.

Comment: Can you post the exact formula?

Comment: ignore me. I've got it working now. Thanks for help